# How can i redirect one url to another url with htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want redirect from domain.com/temp/xyx/tech-specs to domain.com/temp/xyx/tech-specs/pemf-ts through htaccess. I tried below code but it is not redirecting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /temp/xyx/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tech-specs$
RewriteRule ^$ tech-specs/pemf-ts [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `HTTP_HOST` variable but what you need to match is `REQUEST_URI`. Also keep redirect rule before internal rewrite rule.

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /temp/xyx/

RewriteRule ^(tech-specs)/?$ $1/pemf-ts [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```